# How to open the window with JTable and close another

Tags: java, swing, window, jtable, jframe

I have problem when I want to close some frame and open that which have table made in `JTable` inside. In console appears a lot of errors. My code work when I want close and open another frame but not with `JTable`.

I create table this way:

```
public table(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        String [] kolumny={"name of columns"};
        Object [][] dane ={
                {"","","","",""},
                {"","","","",""},

        };
        table=new JTable(dane,kolumny);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,50));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
        table qui = new table();
        qui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        qui.setSize(500,500);
        qui.setVisible(true);
        qui.setTitle("Tabela");
```

Code that close and open another frame:

```
JMenuItem jakas nazwa = new JMenuItem("jakas nazwa");
        akcja.add(jakas nazwa);
        jakas nazwa.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new qui().setVisible(true);  
            Nazwa okienka które zamykamy.this.dispose();
        }

    });
```

Some errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.isInstanceOf(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installProperty(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalButtonUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `table` inside the `table` constructor. that's why you're getting a `stackoverflow`. It's an infinite loop.

Take this out:

```
table qui = new table();
```

And just use this

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(500,500);
setVisible(true);
setTitle("Tabela");
```

---

Side Note: Use Java naming convention. Classes begin with capital letters